# Database Replication not starting

Tags: marklogic

I have two servers with the same MarkLogic version and with an unrestricted network connection. Both servers run CentOS with Marklogic 7.0-3.

I have a fully loaded database on server1, I have an empty database on server2.
My goal is to replicate this database from server1 to server2 and keep it in sync.

To set this up, I follow the Database Replication guide on the MarkLogic website.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/quick_start

I couple the clusters, I create the Database Replication configuration, all fine and without any errors. I check the last Boostrap (typo made by MarkLogic) and it does not say 'never' so there has been a kind of communication between the clusters.

And then nothing. Not a single document or fragment gets synced. Not a single error message in the log files of these servers. The last line in the log file of the 'slave' system is:

```
2014-07-03 14:06:30.184 Info: Forest dbase-content-001-1 accepts foreign forest {server1-cluster dbase-content dbase-content-001-1} as its master with new precise time 14038608798546100
```

Also, the database state of the 'slave' is; 'syncing replica'. But it's not doing anything.
When I check the server load, both servers are idle.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to mblakele and Wayne Feick I found out one of the servers had no synchronized time. After configuring localtime, NTP and syncing both of them, the Database Replication is running.

The warning pointing at my problem.

```
2014-07-04 00:00:50.923 Warning: Excessive clock skew detected; suggest using NTP (7201 seconds skew with server2 in foreign cluster server2-cluster)
```

The message after syncing the time.

```
2014-07-04 08:06:01.588 Info: Saved 10 MB in 1 sec at 17 MB/sec to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00000013
```

The remaining challenge is getting the slave database to re-index after syncing the data. This is usually only done when inserting new documents in the master database.
This is fixed by setting the indexes and then clearing the database so a new sync starts and the indexes get created.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple trace flags that can provide more information: "Forest Replicate", and "Database Replicate". Those will add additional logging to ErrorLog.txt.

If you're not familiar with trace flags, they can be enabled through the Admin UI by navigating to your group, then clicking on "Diagnostics" in the tree on the left. Be sure to both add the trace flags and also set "trace events activated" to true.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with this the first time I tried it, but it's been a while and I don't remember the details. First I'd turn logging up: in the group config, set "File log level" to `debug` on both clusters. That should give you more chatter in `ErrorLog.txt`.

Check the cluster status on both sides: problems may appear there. And https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication/status may help.